# Read from a database created in another activity - all steps

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I have managed to create database and have methods for saving data. That is in my 2nd activity (being opened from 1st activity). I want to open that database in 1st activity and read from it (if there are any data there now).

What are all steps and things I have to do?

I have tried importing SQLiteOpenHelper class from 2nd activity and reading that way, but no results. Also, tried placing completely the same SQLiteOpenHelper, both on 1st and 2nd activity, and that's not right, too.

EDIT:
Here's my code for creating and saving database which is in 2nd activity:
[Android app crashing on calling SQLiteHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837444/android-app-crashing-on-calling-sqlitehelper/15837489#15837489)

EDIT [2]:
I have tried sth like this:
My 2nd activity (inside SQLiteDbHelper):

```
public String getSP(){
        String sp;          
        String[] projection = {
                SQLiteDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_SP, SQLiteDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_ST};
        Cursor cursor = null;
        cursor = this.getReadableDatabase().query(SQLiteDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor != null){
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                sp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SQLiteDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_SP));
                return sp;
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        return " - ";
    }
```

And, in my 1st activity, where I need the result from the database:

```
String sp = SQLiteDbHelper.getSP();
```

but, it0s causing the error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method

What should I do?

Comment: how are you writing to the database?  The basic way of doing this is to write your own SQLiteHelper class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper. Then you get an instance of SQLiteDatabase and call getReadableDatabase() or getWritableDatabase().  Can you verify you are actually writing to the DB?

Comment: @ Tom Casper - yes, I'm using my own SQLiteHelper that is extending SQLiteOpenHelper.. and I'm for sure writing to a DB.. but how to get an instance of my own SQLiteHelper when it's in the another activity?

Comment: Edited some things, can you please help me now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete and correct answer would be this:

```
import myprojectname.ActivityB.SQLiteDbHelper;
```

and then use:

```
SQLiteDbHelper db = new SQLiteDbHelper(this);
String sp = SQLiteDbHelper.getSP();
```

Thanks for everyone sharing their ideas, they helped me to get to this!

Answer (score 2):

In my own Android app, I created a class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper. Any Activity can create an instance of this class in order to communicate with the database. You can see the complete code of my class [here](https://github.com/codeguru42/bbct/blob/devel/android/common/lib/src/bbct/android/common/database/BaseballCardSQLHelper.java) if you want an example.

Comment: Would you mind going to link in my EDIT part of the question and write me code example of one class to put into my SQLiteHelper and what to call in other activity to get value?

Comment: I posted an example of how to use an SQLiteOpenHelper as answer

Comment: Thanks for idea! It helped me get to my solution.

Comment: @JohnnyAlmi Please accept the answer which you found the most helpful and relevant to your question.

Comment: can't do it until tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Here, use this example from extending the SQLiteOpenHelper

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class YourSQLAdapter {
public static final String DBNAME  = "filename.db";
public static final String TABLE   = "tablename";
public static final int    VERSION = 1;

public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    // Add other fields here

private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
private Context mContext;

    //this is how I write the create db script, you may do it you own way;)
public static String a = "TEXT";
public static String b = "INTEGER";
public static String c = "PRIMARY KEY";
public static String d = "AUTOINCREMENT";
public static String e = " ";
public static String f = ",";

private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
      "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE + e + "(" + 
      KEY_ID  + e + b + e + c + e + d + f + e + ");";


public YourSQLAdapter(Context context){
    mContext = context;
}

public void close() {
    sqLiteHelper.close();
}

public int deleteAll() {
    return sqLiteDatabase.delete(TABLE, null, null);
}

public long insert(String value) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    rooster.put("fieldname(or use its key value)", value);
    return sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE, null, cv);
}

public YourSQLAdapter openToRead() throws SQLException {
    try {
        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(mContext, DBNAME, null, 1);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    } catch (Exception e){}
    return this;
}

public YourSQLAdapter openToWrite() throws SQLException {
    try {
        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(mContext, DBNAME, null, 1);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (Exception e){}
    return this;
}

public Cursor queueAll() {
    String[] KEYS = { KEY_ID /* and all other KEYS*/ };
    return sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE, KEYS, null, null, null, null, null);
}

public Cursor queueDay(String query) {
    String[] KEYS = { KEY_ID /* and all other KEYS*/ };
    return sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE, KEYS, query, null, null, null, null);
}

public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion) {}
}
}
```

When you create the DB use

```
YourSQLAdapter sql = new YourSQLAdapter(context);
sql.openToWrite();
```

and if you want to read from the DB use

```
YourSQLAdapter sql = new YourSQLAdapter(context);
sql.openToRead();
```

Warning, if the DB is not created yet, you get an exception on openToRead() because the SQLiteOpenHelper sees it does not exist yet and tries to create it(which cant because it can't write)

Hope this helps;)

Comment: Thanks for idea! It helped me get to my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You're interacting with your db from an Activity, that isn't a good way to go about it.  You should create a plain class file separate of either Activity that extends SQLiteOpenHelper and has public methods you create for the direct interactions of reading and writing to your database.  A quick search [shows some good examples of doing this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14616629/1305064)

Then anywhere you need to call data from it (like from either of your Activites) or write to db you'd only need something like...

```
MyDBClassName db = new MyDBClassName();
String someStoredValue = db.readFromTable(RowID-or-searchargs);
```

What methods are available to you (that is, db.readFromTable) would be determined by what methods you setup in this class file.

Comment: MyDBClassName db = new MyDBClassName(); is not working, it needs some context to be added to new MyDBClassName()

Comment: Thanks for idea! It helped me get to my solution.

Comment: Oh yea.  Well you could pass the context in as one of the inputs of making a new class instance of the class you create.   Like have in the method that shares the class name (which is essentially the 'start method' of the class) an input argument for the context.  Only changed from what I wrote would be initializing it as `MyDBClassName db = new MyDBClassName(this);`  The `this` value should work ok for any activities, other not activities might need `getApplicationContext();` instead but I think you get the idea.

Comment: Also, glad to hear you figured it out.  Please choose an answer to accept so this question shows as closed/answered.

Comment: maybe I should have known it all from your comment, but I'm new to Android programming (really new), so I'm still trying to catch everything. will accept answer in 1 hour, can't do it earlier