# How to pass an object with an Intent

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I have an `alarm`(repeatingalarm) and `BroadcastReceiver` to handle it. the alarm is set in my `activity` with pending intent referring to `BroadcastReceiver` class. I have a `sqlite` database in my activity. i want to update my sqlite database in my alarm so i need sqlite object from my activity. it is needed for my `asynctask` too which is executed in my alarm too. how can i do that?
in short terms, i want to pass my activity object to my broadcast constructor so i can use my sqlite instance.

EDIT: I noticed that if i define `BroadcastReciever` inside my activity, i can refer to it as simple as **MyActivity.this**. is there any other way rather than this.

Comment: you can not doing too much work in  'broadcastreceiver' .

Comment: define all classes inside my activity. can i get access to my activity class object from them?

Comment: Yes you can call any method from any class accept its not update and UI component and you must pass application Context from your calling side ,And you can any method just like any non  Activity Class .

Answer (score 1):

you can not do too much work in  'broadcastreceiver' .

Intend you must create one service class to do this and call service from 'broadcastreceiver' . and then write your DataBase code in `Service` .

In Service you can create '`sqlite`' `DataBase` object through `getApplicationConext()`.

Also within Service must create Seperate Thread for your work or use `AsyncTask` to do your DataBase Operations.

Comment: I need Repeating alarm so i need broadcastreceiver not service.

Comment: Yes you right for broadcastreceiver  but broadcastreceiver  has limited time to do your work , Best approach is that you call service from broadcastreceiver  and then do you task within service ,

Comment: service can be only a way to lauch/fire broadcastreceiver.

Comment: is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856716/read-from-a-database-created-in-another-activity-all-steps) going to help me?

Comment: yeah because your activity can not running for long time. but your service can run for long time in background and you can restart it without getting into app after reboot and much more. Broadcast receiver is used for short tasks only.